# What is the use of Cursor Auto Fetch in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the use of Cursor Auto Fetch in SQL Server?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not something you run across often.  I believe it's an ADO option that tells SQL Server to start getting results as soon as you open a cursor.  The [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173487(SQL.80).aspx) aren't much help, though!